# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Недавно прочитал в интернете:

> Ровно в 5 вечера начался праздничный концерт. На сцене возле Минск-Арены выступили такие группы, как Цвет Алоэ, Без Билета, Минское Море. Особым успехом у публики пользовалась группа Без Билета, которую зрители, после окончания их выступления, никак не хотели отпускать.

Меня насторожило выражение "после окончания их выступления". Стоит ли его предавать обособлению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст - хороший пример того, как двумя-тремя стилистическим и орфографическим погрешностями можно напрочь отбить желание читать. Не до факультативных обособлений. Вообще я обычно не предлагаю варианты редакторской правки вместо ответа по существу, но тут ничего другого не остаётся.

**Ровно в 5 вечера начался праздничный концерт. На сцене возле "Минск-Арены" выступили коллективы "Цвет Алоэ", "Минское Море" (и другие?). Особые симпатии достались группе "Без Билета", которую собравшиеся никак не хотели отпускать после выступления.**

Это тоже далеко не безгрешный вариант, но все ж получше, есть с чем ставнивать.

Некоторые пояснения.
~1. Убраны все канцелярские связки, повторы слов (репортаж все-таки).
~2. "Пользовалась успехом" - тут плохо, нужен глагол совершенного вида, да и вообще оборот сомнителен в даннном значении.
~3. "Зрители" на музыкальных концертах отсылает к "просмотру оперы" и "слушателям балета".

Answer (score 0):

Мои мысли по данному поводу.

1. Это писали не профессиональные журналисты, а был ли корректор или редактор - вопрос. Поэтому я бы сильно не переживал.
2. Выделение запятыми наверняка возможно. Интонационно я могу его передать. По этому поводу см.[п.Б3](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_5_2) и [§94 п.4](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#з_03)
3. Меня бы больше беспокоило другое. А именно - "после окончания их выступления" или "после окончания ее [группы Без Билета] выступления".

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю выделение обстоятельства в данном случае все-таки авторским знаком. Не случайно у Розенталя сплошь примеры из художественной литературы. 
ЧТо касается употребления местоимения, то автор первого ответа прав. Местоимение должно быть в единственном числе: после выступления *группы* - после *её* выступления.

Answer (score 0):

А меня насторожило написание названий групп без кавычек. Выражение "после окончания их выступления" я бы не обособляла.